# DockerCompose for ASP.NET Core API App and Angular6 App

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, dockerfile

Good day,

I'm new with docker. I have 2 projects that have dockerfiles in each of them.

My projects are: ASP.NET Core API and Angular6

In my ASP.NET Core API project, here's my working dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/DockerPublishedApp} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

I did manually published my app and it stores in my DockerPublishedApp.

In my Angular6 project, here's my working dockerfile.

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY /dist/mypublishedangularapp /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Both these dockerfiles are working properly when I build and run them one by one.

My main concern is, how can I convert them to `docker-compose.yml` to avoid running the created image one by one.

Comment: Docker Compose will not merge your images, only orchestrate the containers when running, you still need the Dockerfiles. What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following directory structure:

```
    /proj1
        /Dockerfile
    /proj2
        /Dockerfile
    /docker-compose.yml
```

You could have the following compose file:

```
    version: '3.4'

    services:
      proj1:
        image: proj1:latest     
        build:
          context: ./proj1
          dockerfile: Dockerfile

      proj2:
        image: proj2:latest     
        build:
          context: ./proj2
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build` to build both images and run them. This will build images proj1:latest and proj2:latest.

Alternatively, if you did not want to build them, just remove the build keys, and omit --build.

---

To run publish out of the Dockerfile:

```
    version: '3.4'

    services:
      proj1:
        image: proj1:latest     
        build:
          context: ./proj1
          dockerfile: Dockerfile 
        command: dotnet publish ...
```

Comment: Is there a way sir to automatically publish both of them as well inside the docker-compose.yml? because in my dockerfile, I manually publish the asp.net core and the angular app.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, as I haven't any use of publishing outside of the Dockerfile. But if you really want to, you could can see my edit.

Comment: You should publish within the Dockerfile. The stock Dockerfile created when you make a new .net project in VS should be ok to use. Every time you make a change to the codebase, you run the docker-compose command above to rebuild. Docker will cache the unchanged Dockerfile steps for you.

Comment: I'm on mac so I need to manually create those dockerfiles. I want do something like in VS for Windows where you can add automatically the docker-compose.yml. Then that docker-compose.yml, automatically republish each changes you made in the code.

Comment: what do you mean by `command` there in docker-compose.yml file? is it where I need to put my publish command? like in angular6, it's `ng build` and in asp.net core, `dotnet publish ...`?

Comment: Use a variation of this Dockerfile: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile. And yes, you can run dotnet publish from command (see edit)

Comment: I'm having a problem putting command there. It says similar to `DockerPublishedApp` no such file or directory

Comment: cd /app && dotnet publish ... && dotnet myapp.dll